# How to tell which html element sent http request on server side?

Tags: html, node.js, server

I have registration and login form on same page and both of them are sent via POST request. How can i distinguish them in my post request handler function so that server responds accordingly. Is the element that sent request included in request body?

Comment: The form submit button is sent with the form data.  You could use that.  But, keep in mind that not everyone submits forms with a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include some sort of metadata with the request to indicate which operation is sending the information.

This could be a hidden field or just an additional bit of JSON added on the client side:

```
<input type="hidden" id="formID" name="formID" value="login">
```

---

```
<input type="hidden" id="formID" name="formID" value="registration">
```

Another option would be to set up different targets on your server (i.e. different paths) that each form submits to separately.

Comment: Was able to make it work by adding type property (reg/login) to JSON, read it on server side and remove before appending acquired data. Thank you !